# Pi4B: touch LCD+HDMI monitor, touch area issues

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, touchscreen

I have a Pi4B with a fresh install of Raspbian. I have a [4" touch LCD](http://www.lcdwiki.com/4inch_HDMI_Display-C) on HDMI0, and a 13" non-touch portable monitor on HDMI1, and I configured the workspaces so they don't overlap. I enabled touch with the following changes in config.txt:

```
dtparam=spi=on
hdmi_cvt 480 800 60 6 0 0 0
dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=25,penirq_pull=2,speed=50000,keep_vref_on=0,swapxy=0,pmax=255,xohms=150,xmin=200,xmax=3900,ymin=200,ymax=3900
```

(i didn't do the full install as recommended on that link, as that kills my ability to use 2 screens - see my previous question)

However, when using the touch screen, each point is mapped to the whole workspace instead of just the LCD. In other words, if I hit the bottom right corner of the LCD, the Pi registers a click at the bottom right of the large screen.

It probably sounds a bit confusing so an image being worth 1000 words:
[image]
Red is (approximately) where I touch; green is where it registers.

Note that this isn't actually affected by whether the second screen is connected or not.

Anybody know what I need to fiddle with to solve it? I just want to use the touch screen for touch input.

Answer (score 0):

`xinput map-to-output <touch device ID> HDMI-1` 
did it for me.